# Custom Dynamic Layer draws below annotations

Tags: arcgis-engine

My custom dynamic layer (moving vehicles) is at position 0, specified by this code:

```
mapControl.Map.MoveLayer(customDynamicLayer, 0); //smaller numbers draw later
```

But the annotations of the layer at position 1 (my map) still draw over my dynamic layer.  Is this normal?   Is there a workaround?   I'm guessing there isn't a workaround because the non-dynamic layers get tiled, but I thought I'd ask anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The drawing order within a layer is fixed, annotations always draw above geography.

There is a good [description of drawing order](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/dotnet/2a1de2c3-0c3e-412e-8e1e-1a29d657be8c.htm#Order) and drawing phases in the ESRI documentation.